# TypeORM OneToMany relation doesn't add entry to the array when it is created

Tags: sql, database, orm, typeorm

I am trying to create two entities - `Assignment` and `Lesson`. Each `Lesson` can have multiple `Assignment`s and each `Assignment` can be part of one `Lesson`. When I create a `Lesson` with `Assignment`s in it, the `Assignemnt`s get created, they are added to the `assignments` array and everything works.

When I create a `Lesson` and then try to add a new `Assignment` to it, the `Assignment` is created, it is linked to the correct `Lesson` but the `assignments` field in the Lesson is not updated.

Is this how it is supposed to work or is there any way to update the `assignments` array in `Lesson`?

Below is my code. I am using a sqlite in-memory database

Assignment.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, TableInheritance, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Lesson } from './Lesson';

@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: 'varchar', name: 'type' } })
export abstract class Assignment {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Lesson, (lesson) => lesson.assignments, { eager: true })
    @Column('json')
    lesson: Lesson;
}
```

Lesson.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Assignment } from './Assignment';

@Entity()
export class Lesson {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Assignment, (assignment) => assignment.lesson, { cascade: true })
    @Column('json')
    assignments: Assignment[];
}
```

I have tried adding `@JoinColumn()` to the `@ManyToOne` relation but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the `@Column` annotation from both of the fields - assignments and lesson.

I could also add a filed `lessonId: number` with the `@Column` annotation to store the lesson id in the Assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add your code that shows how you are accessing your data... but Ill take a stab:

typically you'll add a lesson to an assignment as follows:

```
const lesson = await Lesson.findOne({where:{id:1},relations:['assignments]})
const assignment = await Assignment.findOne({where:{id:1}}
assignment.lesson = assignment
await assignment.save()
// at this point lesson wont have your new assignment
// you could just add it to the lesson.assignments array
lesson.assignments.push(assignment)
// or you could re-read from the db
const lessonAfterAdd = 
await Lesson.findOne({where:{id:1},relations['assignments]})
```